# In R. What is the average Loan Amount for the 'High' Income_Level group

Tags: r, dataframe, mean

In R. What is the average Loan Amount for the 'High' Income_Level group?

```
Income_Level <- c('High','Low','Low','High',
                  'Low','High','High','High','Low','Low','High','Low')
Loan_Amount <- c(1000,250,300,925,100,750,600,875,150,400,600,250)
Loan_data <- data.frame(Income_Level,Loan_Amount)
Loan_data
```

I've been messing around with the mean function but can't seem to specifically find the average Loan_Amount for the 'High' Income_Level group. This is how I'm picturing the code for this answer but it's just not working out.

```
mean(Loan_data$Loan_Amount,Loan_data$Income_Level == 'High')
```

I appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Use `tapply` but all groups means will output in named vector but you can index it: `tapply(Loan_data$Loan_Amount, Loan_data$Income_Level, mean)['High']`

Comment: `mean(unlist(subset(Loan_data, Income_Level=="High")[2]))`

Comment: These both work great. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

```
mean(Loan_data[Loan_data$Income_Level == "High", ]$Loan_Amount)
[1] 791.6667
```

Explanation:
First, we subset the dataframe for those with high income

```
Loan_data[Loan_data$Income_Level == "High", ]
Income_Level Loan_Amount
1          High        1000
4          High         925
6          High         750
7          High         600
8          High         875
11         High         600
```

and then we subset the Loan_Amount

```
Loan_data[Loan_data$Income_Level == "High", ]$Loan_Amount
[1] 1000  925  750  600  875  600
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `tidyverse` approach:

```
library(tidyverse)

Income_Level <- c('High','Low','Low','High',
                  'Low','High','High','High','Low','Low','High','Low')
Loan_Amount <- c(1000,250,300,925,100,750,600,875,150,400,600,250)
Loan_data <- data.frame(Income_Level,Loan_Amount)
Loan_data %>% 
    group_by(Income_Level) %>% 
    summarise(Average_Loan_Amount=mean(Loan_Amount,na.rm=TRUE))
```

This is the result:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  Income_Level Average_Loan_Amount
  <fct>                      <dbl>
1 High                         792
2 Low                          242
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it has to do with the dataframe construct. It works if you subset the data you want to analyze, if you're able to do that:

```
Loan_data2 <- Loan_data[Income_Level == 'High',]
mean(Loan_data2$Loan_Amount)
```